# C++ Why can I not save this pointer to a reference?

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, reference

I wish to get a pointer to a value-element (a struct) of a map, and save this pointer in a vector.

What is wrong with the second example?

Example 1 (compiles but wrong semantics)

```
vector<Tstruct*> myvector {};

for (const map<int, Tstruct> &kv : mymap) {
    auto y = kv.second;      // a copy
    myvector.push_back(&y);  // ok! &y is a Tstruct*, but this is a pointer to a copy
}
```

Example 2 (does not compile but purports to show intended semantics)

```
vector<Tstruct*> myvector {};

for (const map<int, Tstruct> &kv : mymap) {
    myvector.push_back(&kv.second); // &kv.second is not a valid argument here (why?)
}
```

I realise this must be a newbie question but searched around and could not figure it out exactly; i understood that the "address of reference to X" = "address of X", so this seems a little odd.

Comment: `for (const map<int, Tstruct> &kv : mymap)` is this the correct code? Is it a map of maps? Please create a [mcve] - including compiler errors.

Comment: if `&kv.second` will not fit in `myvector`, it stands to reason that you ought to show what `myvector` is. Pretty must all of your answers will be found in that bit of information. That said, if you make a [mre], odds are really good that you'll see and be able to fix the problem yourself. Asking a question without having already constructed a MRE is usually a waste of your time.

Comment: #Quimby it has been adapted from a more complicated example that used auto instead of ```map<int, Tstruct>``` and it initially read sth like ```for (const auto &kv : mymap) { myvector.push_back(&kv.second); }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop, `kv` is declared as `const`, so the `kv.second` field is a `const Tstruct`. Taking its address will produce a `const Tstruct*` pointer. But the `vector` wants a non-const `Tstruct*` pointer instead. Which is why your 1st example works but you 2nd example fails.

Note that your 1st example is giving the `vector`  a pointer to a local `Tstruct*` variable that goes out of scope immediately after the push, leaving the `vector` with a dangling pointer.

If `mymap` is not `const` then `kv` doesn't need to be `const`, either:

```cpp
for (map<int, Tstruct> &kv : mymap) {
    myvector.push_back(&kv.second);
```